# Traceback while trying to run dell-recovery

Tags: dell, python

While trying to run dell-recovery, I am getting this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dell-recovery", line 24, in <module>
    from Dell.recovery_common import find_partition, check_version, find_burners
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Dell/recovery_common.py", line 29, in <module>
    gi.require_version('UDisks', '2.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 130, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace UDisks not available
```

Even though I do have Udisks installed (2.7.6-3ubuntu0.2).
Thanks in advance.